# In Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2, WO list page in sidemenu option, while clicking "Download work list" while downloading , clicking of cancel button issue

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Maximo anywhere 7.5.2, In WO list page in sidemenu option, click on "Download work list" option, while downloading , clicking of cancel button, not able to cancel the downloading records, getting below some of error. Please help me to solve the issue.

TypeError:Window.requestfilesystem is not a function
.findNonExistingAndMergeExistingRecords rvices/preview/WorkExecution/common/1.0/default/js/platform/store/StoreLock.js:73:34)
    at Object

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a bug.  Please open a PMR on this with our support team.